# Separate build directory using xcodebuild

Tags: macos, xcodebuild

The man page for `xcodebuild` reads:

> Run xcodebuild from the directory
>   containing your project (i.e. the
>   directory containing the
>   projectname.xcodeproj package).

I would like to keep my source directory (which is a Subversion external) clean and unmodified, and build my object files and executables to a location completely outside of the source directory.

Is there any way to build into a separate build directory from a terminal using `xcodebuild` like you can do with `make` tools or even `msbuild` on Windows?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can set build settings from the command line. The `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` will set the build directory. For example:

```
xcodebuild -project YourProject.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -target All ARCHS=x86_64 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=../some/other/dir
```

A reference is found on Apple's site:

- [Build Setting Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html)

Comment: I found that I also needed to set CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR, and then this worked for me.

Comment: You can just set BUILD_DIR and that will work too :D

Answer (score 13):

To achieve complete separation the following build settings have to be changed (more than just `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` like accepted answer suggests), otherwise Xcode still builds some of its artifacts under its default build folder.

On my machine Xcode normally builds everything to `./Build` and `./DerivedData` where current directory is one of my project.

I wanted xcodebuild to build everything under `Build-command-line` folder so I used `xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme -showBuildSettings | grep Build\/` to find all build settings that correspond to all build paths and by trial-end-error I found "the generative" build settings that are enough to redirect **all build artefacts produced by xcodebuild** to custom folder.

I ended up using the following command:

```
BUILD_DIR=./Build-command-line
DERIVED_DATA_DIR=$(BUILD_DIR)/DerivedData

xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj \
         -IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks=`sysctl -n hw.ncpu` \
         -scheme MyScheme \
         -sdk iphonesimulator \
         -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6S Plus,OS=latest' \
         -xcconfig command-line-build.xcconfig \
         -derivedDataPath $(DERIVED_DATA_DIR) \
         test
```

Where `command-line-build.xcconfig` is:

```
HERE_BUILD=$(SRCROOT)/Build-command-line
HERE_INTERMEDIATES=$(HERE_BUILD)/Intermediates

// Paths
// the following paths are enough to redirect everything to $HERE_BUILD
MODULE_CACHE_DIR    = $(HERE_BUILD)/DerivedData/ModuleCache
OBJROOT             = $(HERE_INTERMEDIATES)
SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = $(HERE_INTERMEDIATES)/PrecompiledHeaders
SYMROOT
```

**Note:** Make sure you use absolute paths in your xcconfig, otherwise you may have error: [Xcode crashing on startup “parentPath must be nil but it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37610590/598057).

I have written a post about this solution with a bit of background: [xcodebuild: how to really change its build path](http://stanislaw.github.io/2016/02/28/xcodebuild-how-to-really-change-its-build-path.html).

P.S. Of course this information is subject to change but as of `Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)` it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Stanislav, you may be (the only person :) ) who knows [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024900/what-the-heck-is-xcbuilddata-and-why-are-the-build-folders-not-actually-updated)    :O

Comment: No, I don’t. Sorry :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but at least for scenarios that I personally encounter (with Xcode 13), the problem with SYMROOT, OBJROOT, SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR and others not affected by -derivedDataPath is solved by adding -IDECustomBuildProductsPath="" and  -IDECustomBuildIntermediatesPath="" to xcodebuild invocation, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71550519/1859783 below.

Answer (score 8):

## Xcode 10

For a Workspace if you're using CocoaPods:

```
xcodebuild -workspace youProject.xcworkspace -scheme yourScheme -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release SYMROOT=$(PWD)/build
```

That will put your .app in `./build/Release-iphonesimulator`

Answer (score 5):

In my project, setting `SYMROOT` turned out to be sufficient to build the project in a different location, leaving other locations untouched.

From Apple's [Xcode Build Setting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) (which I came across via another answer here, thanks!):

> **SYMROOT** (Build Products Path)
>
> Description: Directory path. Identifies the root of the directory hierarchy that contains product files and intermediate build files. Product and build files are placed in subdirectories of this directory.
>
> ...
>
> Affects: BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR, CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR (...)

This setting is also mentioned a few times in the `xcodebuild` man page:

> Available actions are:
>
> build: Build the target in the build root (SYMROOT)...
>
> clean: Remove build products and intermediate files from the build root (SYMROOT)....

Comment: If you want to redirect **everything** to a custom folder, at least `OBJROOT` is very important because quite a few of folders depend on it, not on `SYMROOT`. I have just checked Xcode 7.3.1 - MODULE_CACHE_DIR and SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR are also independent of `SYMROOT`. So your answer will still build some stuff to default build directory however maybe that is enough for your task.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the `SYMROOT` build setting to your desired location.  All of the other relevant build settings are derived from it.

Answer (score 1):

If -derivedDataPath does not do the trick, add -IDECustomBuildProductsPath="" and -IDECustomBuildIntermediatesPath="" to xcodebuild invocation, like below:

```
xcodebuild -derivedDataPath /custom/path -IDECustomBuildProductsPath="" -IDECustomBuildIntermediatesPath="" ...
```

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71550483/1859783

Answer (score 0):

You can also temporarily change the working directory and run the command from there.  i.e.

```
 (cd dir1/dir2/MyApp && xcodebuild build -workspace "MyApp.xcworkspace" -scheme "MyApp")
```