# Xcode crashing on startup "parentPath must be nil but it is not"

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, xcode7

I'm having XCode (latest version) crash whenever I start up - can't get anything done until I resolve this - any ideas?

1. Error - See below
2. What I did prior to getting the issue

   - had put in a new HDD (and moved the old to the optical bay) - reinstalled XCode 4 on the new SSD - all working fine
   - I did rename my home directory user name on the "old" HDD to put "_OLD" at the end - just so I didn't get confused if jumping to the old HDD for files
   - I tried to open a test project from this old HDD area - got some issue opening it (can't remember details) - closed/restarted fromhere
   - Then after this every time I try to open XCode a fresh it's like it tries to open the last projects that was open including this one I had an issue with - get the below error - can't continue on using xcode have to crash out

Error:

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-903/Framework/Classes/FilePaths/DVTFilePath.m:322
Details:  fsrep is absolute (starts with tilde) ('~--814203924d469071-0000000000') parentPath must be nil but it is not ('<DVTFilePath:0x401bdf9e0:'/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/greg/.dvdcss'>')
Object:   <DVTFilePath>
Method:   +_filePathForParent:fileSystemRepresentation:length:allowCreation:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a260>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000103f44466 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001035b3794 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000103550a9e +[DVTFilePath _filePathForParent:fileSystemRepresentation:length:allowCreation:] (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000103550963 +[DVTFilePath _filePathForParent:pathString:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000103b95642 -[DVTFilePath(IDESourceControlStatus) IDESourceControl_importantSubpaths] (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x0000000103b414ac -[IDEFileReference _updateSourceControlStatusIfNeeded] (in IDEFoundation)
  6  0x0000000103b37951 -[IDEWorkspace _updateSourceControlStatusIfNeeded] (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x00007fff8c2eb25a __NSFireDelayedPerform (in Foundation)
  8  0x00007fff8b82df84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
  9  0x00007fff8b82dad6 __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
10  0x00007fff8b80e471 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
11  0x00007fff8b80dae6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
12  0x00007fff8b3633d3 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
13  0x00007fff8b36a63d ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
14  0x00007fff8b36a4ca BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
15  0x00007fff86bde3f1 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
16  0x00007fff86bddcf5 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
17  0x00007fff86bda62d -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
18  0x00007fff86e5980c NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
19  0x0000000103549eec (in Xcode)
20  0x0000000000000002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may not be best answer (?) however I had to (a) reinstall + (b) delete all the various XCode files scattered through my home directory...then it started up ok

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
It was due to a file fo which the name started by ~ in the directory path given by Xcode when it crashed.

Check if you don't have such a file and delete it.

In my case, it solved the issue.

Hope this help,

Rds,

Michael

Comment: Yep. In my case it was some Microsoft Excel files saved in the Xcode folder; Excel creates backups beginning with a tilde. The path where the problem files are is shown in the error report.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me is to delete the Xcode autosave files in ~/Library/Autosave Information.  Xcode then started up clean for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, thanks!  Make sure to delete all "Unsaved XCode" files and you should be a-okay.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Copy all the code you want to keep into text files or
  something like that
- Step 2: Un-install
- Step 3: make some coffee
- Step 4: Re-install

Comment: tried this but it didn't work - seems there are various XCode pref/cache type files in your home directory which don't get uninstalled with the XCode uninstall

Comment: yeah youll have to go in and find anything to do with xcode and delete it after uninstall. Just after its gone, search for anything with the word xcode in it and straight up delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Details:  fsrep is absolute (starts with tilde) ('~--814203924d469071-0000000000') parentPath must be nil but it is not ('<DVTFilePath:0x401bdf9e0:'/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/greg/.dvdcss'>')
Object:   <DVTFilePath>
```

in my case the file referenced was dropbox's cache, so the error looked like this

```
must be nil but it is not ('<DVTFilePath:0x401bdf9e0:'/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/greg/.dropbox.cache.2.25.12'>')
```

after some research on dropbox forums i found these cache directories can be deleted.  after removal xcode worked fine.

so i would tell future people who come here to try and remove the offending file prior to reinstalling xcode. (or rename it if you cant delete it)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist and Xcode started normally again.

Comment: I was able to get the "accept license" window after this but that's it. It started to crash again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was xcodebuild'ing Xcode UI Tests from command line using custom .xcconfig file:

```
HERE_BUILD=./Build-command-line
HERE_INTERMEDIATES=$(HERE_BUILD)/Intermediates

// Paths
// the following paths are enough to redirect everything to $HERE_BUILD
MODULE_CACHE_DIR    = $(HERE_BUILD)/DerivedData/ModuleCache
OBJROOT             = $(HERE_INTERMEDIATES)
SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = $(HERE_INTERMEDIATES)/PrecompiledHeaders
SYMROOT             = $(HERE_BUILD)/Products
```

When I changed HERE_BUILD to have absolute path:

```
HERE_BUILD=$(SRCROOT)/Build-command-line
```

the error went away.