# xcodebuild ignoring -derivedDataPath

Tags: xcodebuild

Am I misunderstanding what `-derivedDataPath` does, or is this a bug? You can clearly see in the output that xcodebuild is ignoring the command-line value, and defaulting to `Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.

```
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project MyProj.xcodeproj -scheme “MyProj (iOS)" -destination "name=iPhone 12" -derivedDataPath=/Users/alpe77/myproj/MyProj/Build build

User defaults from command line:
    derivedDataPath = /Users/alpe77/myproj/MyProj/Build
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Using build description from disk
note: Build preparation complete
CodeSign /Users/alpe77/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-aozsidihjyumkvevtfoqflhumohn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.app (in target 'MyProj (iOS)' from project 'MyProj')
cd /Users/alpe77/myproj/MyProj
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "-"

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --entitlements 
/Users/alpe77/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-aozsidihjyumkvevtfoqflhumohn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj\ \(iOS\).build/MyProj.app.xcent --timestamp\=none 
/Users/alpe77/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-aozsidihjyumkvevtfoqflhumohn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.app
/Users/alpe77/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-aozsidihjyumkvevtfoqflhumohn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.app: replacing existing signature

** BUILD SUCCEEDED ** [0.771 sec]

% xcrun xcodebuild -version 
Xcode 12.5.1
Build version 12E507
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem (Xcode 12.4) and found out that the build environment configuration variable `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` overrides the path given in `-derivedDataPath`

I opened "Xcode Preferences > Locations > Derived Data > Advanced" and changed the build location setting from my custom setting to "Unique" which solved the problem.

Would be interested in how to prevent `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` from overriding `-derivedDataPath` on the command line, though...

*Edit*

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35662727/403750 for a solution.

Comment: One way to see which value `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` has when `xcodebuild` runs is to add the `-showBuildSettings` command line option.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could figure out, at least for Xcode 13, xcodebuild ignores `-derivedDataPath` for build products/intermediates, *if* they're overridden in Xcode defaults, in e.g. Xcode Preferences > Locations > Derived Data > Advanced - they're derived from Derived Data set in Xcode defaults, not from the one passed to xcodebuild. As a workaround, we can "clear" those defaults as well, when invoking xcodebuild like below (luckily they're clearly visible in the list of defaults for com.apple.dt.Xcode, as IDECustomBuildProductsPath and IDECustomBuildIntermediatesPath, and xcodebuild supports overriding the custom defaults in general by passing `-userdefault=value`):

```
xcodebuild -derivedDataPath /custom/path -IDECustomBuildProductsPath="" -IDECustomBuildIntermediatesPath="" ...
```